# Why are intensive variables easier to control than extensive?

Tags: thermodynamics

In a IUPAC Technical Report (***Alberty***, Use of Legender Transforms in Chemical Thermodynamics, [pdf](http://users.df.uba.ar/ariel/materias/FT3_2008_1C/papers_pdf/legendre_3.pdf)) I have found the following assertion (p. 1359):

> "Intensive variables are introduced because they are often easier to control than extensible variables."

Without any further explanation. I does not hurt my scientific feeling but I am looking for a good justification.

I will assume that control means you are first able to measure it and then you may be able to regulate it.

I would agree with this affirmation for system at equilibrium. In this case, measuring intensive variables (such as temperature, pressure or wind speed) is not a big deal because the scalar/vector field is homogeneous or easily modeled and you do not need to analyze the whole system in order to complete your measurement. Instead accurately measuring volume or amount of matter might be not trivial (eg. for atmospheric system).

But how could this affirmation stand for more general case?

Comment: I remember it as a statement by my Thermodynamics professor. I think it shall be taken as a "in most cases". Certanly, controlling the mass (lock the system in a vase) is easier than controlling the density (lock it in with fixed volume).

Comment: Interesting, in your example it is the opposite: mass (extensive) appears to be easier to control than density (intensive).

Comment: Yes, it is a counterexample. This is why I think it is a rule of thumb more than a law.

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose that intensive variables are easier to control, simply because the thermodynamic state of a material depends only on intensive variables.  Saturated liquid water at a certain temperature has a well-defined specific volume, specific energy, specific entropy, etc, while nothing can be said about the extensive properties of the water.

Intensive variables can be controlled by controlling the state of the substance.

Comment: Just to rain on your parade, have you ever made water have a density of 2? Some intensive variables are easy to control (like temperature). Other are determined by the state of the material (like specific heat), which will have a narrow range.